# Regular Expression TCL using procedure

Tags: regex, tcl

I am a novice TCL programmer. Here I go - My 1st post with stackoverflow forum.

I would like to write a regular expression that matches any & only the strings starts with character A and ends with B. Whatever the characters coming inbetween should be displayed. For instance **AXIOMB** as an input from the user which starts with A & end with character B.

Here is my try

```
regexp { (^A([C-Z]+)B$)}
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One question: What about `ARAB`? Is that a legal word?

Answer (score 3):

You're very close:

```
set stringToTest "AXIOMB"
set match [regexp {^A([C-Z]*)B$} $stringToTest -> substring]
if {$match} {
    puts "The middle was $substring"
}
```

(The `->` is actually an unusual variable name. But here I'm using that symbol because it looks better than using the otherwise-equivalent `someRandomDummyVariable`. :-))

If you're seeking to get the string to test from the command line or the console, here's how:

Command line arguments (without the name of the Tcl interpreter or the script) are presented as a list in the global `argv` list variable. The first one is thus `[lindex $::argv 0]`.

A line can be read from the console via the `gets` command.

```
set line [gets stdin]; # you can use other channel names too, of course
```

Note that, unlike in C, `gets` in Tcl is strongly defended against buffer overflows and the (almost) full power of `scanf()` is about equivalent to `scan [gets stdin] ...` (except for some formats excluded for security reasons).

Comment: @ Thank you very much Donal Fellows. Much appreciated. Just would like to know how to get this string from the user in Command line. In 'C' we use like scanf.